# Illustrator CC keyboard shortcut to select next similar object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

If I have 5 similar elements, say circles or text boxes in a row is there any way to quickly move the selection to the next item similar to being able to tab through browser windows? If not, is there a way to just 'tab' through all items on the artboard without using the mouse?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that this could help (on mac):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: Can you please provide a little more information? What it does? Why it works? etc.

Comment: These are:  select next and select previous shortcuts

Comment: Actually they are select next level up/down in the Layers Panel shortcuts, they don't reference any similarities. They merely select the next object above or below the current selection in the Layers Panel. "Next similar" is not possible. - But these could still be helpful depending upon what the user needs.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is simply not possible.